# Star Rating System, Similar to Amazon

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, dreamweaver

I'm looking at adding a rating system to my site, similar to that seen on Amazon. Basically users can rate the product out of 5 stars.

I've been racking my brains to think of the calculation to get the average customer rating... but I can't think how to do it.

And looking at Amazon's system, I think their caculation may be incorrect. If you take this page for example:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/exec/obidos...2521526-3543861

You can see that the average customer rating should actually be 5 stars as two people have chosen 5 whereas only one has chosen 4.

Any ideas??

Comment: If you don't know how you want to do the calculation, maybe you should think about it a little more. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495509/how-to-balance-number-of-ratings-versus-the-ratings-themselves This could help you.

Comment: @zneak - Yeah. Our OP was thinking amazon's calculation is 'incorrect', but that SO question explains why it *should* be.

Comment: Actually, that type of 'incorrect' might be a little different, but it's still relevant.

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the average by taking the sum and dividing it by the number of values. In the case of ratings, it is the sum of all ratings divided by the number of ratings.

In the case you site, with ratings 5, 5 and 4, the average is (5+5+4)/3, which is 4.666..., and I'd guess they round to the nearest half yielding 4.5 out of 5.

Answer (score 1):

why not try a jquery plugin?

http://orkans-tmp.22web.net/star_rating/index.html

Comment: Hi everyone & Aaron,

I´m using dreamweavercs5, php, mysql, javascript & css to develop a physician’s directory (all the physicians store in the table) if user find physician & want to add review and rate to the particular physician (the page show multiple physicians). I need to rate and add reviews to physicians using a 5 star rate and reviews. I saw many different plugins that rate pages and posts. But, besides posts and pages, what I need is to rate several database records (physicians) in the same post/page. I have a list of links, where users cane rate each one of them.
Any ideas?
Thanks!